# Como fazer mapas no R com processamento em paralelo?

Tags: r

Tenho tentado fazer múltiplos mapas ao mesmo tempo no **R** usando `plot` e processamento em paralelo usando o pacote `snowfall`. Eu fiz a seguinte função `mapas`:

```
mapas <- function (tx,
                  limite)
    {
    # Open o png
    png(filename=paste0("mapas_mpc/",tx,".png"),width = 1365, height = 1024)
    plot.new()
    par(mar=c(0,0,0,0),oma=c(0,0,0,0))

    # Plot South America border
    #map(regions = SA, fill = TRUE, col="gray", border="black")
    plot(limite, col="gray", border="black")

    # Load species shapefile
    tx_shp <- shapefile (paste0("MPC/",tx,".shp"))

    # Plot species shapefile
    plot(tx_shp,col=rgb(0/255,139/255,0/255,alpha=0.5), border="darkgreen" ,lwd=3,add=T)

    # Species name
    nome_sp <- gsub(pattern="_",replacement=" ",tx)

    # Plot species name
    text(x=-97,y=-27, nome_sp,font=4,cex=1.5)

    # Close PNG
    dev.off()
    cat(paste("Mapa de ",tx),"\n")
}
```

Depois disso eu inicio o processamento em paralelo:

```
library(snowfall)

# Strat parallel processing
sfInit(parallel=T,cpus=3)
```

E então eu rodo a função `mapas` em paralelo:

```
sfLapply(x = lista_sp,fun = mapas,limite = am_sul )
```

"lista_sp": is a vector os characters which contains the names of species. "am_sul": is the shapefile of South America boundaries.

Daí tenho o seguinte erro:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 3 nodes produced errors; first error: cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'
```

Eu não quero que meus mapas fiquem na mesmo página do plot, até porque são milhares. E preciso fazer os mapas o mais rápido possível, por isso escolhi o processamento paralelo. Como posso resolver este problema?

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente tem algum mapa que está dando problema na hora de rodar. Só que aí vc acaba perdendo o que já fez. 
Eu recomendo você usar uma função que não pare a execução quando tiver algum erro.

Quando uso códigos em paralelo uso o seguinte workflow:

No Windows:

```
library(doSNOW)
library(foreach)
cl <- makeCluster(2)
registerDoSNOW(cl)
```

No Linux:

```
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(2)
```

Em seguida:

```
plyr::l_ply(lista_sp, plyr::failwith(NULL, function(i, limite){
  mapas(i, limite = am_sul)
}), .parallel = T, limite = am_sul)
```

A função `failwith` modifica a função de forma que ela retorne um valor pré definido (no caso `NULL`) caso algum erro ocorra.

Dessa forma, no fim da execução do loop você pode ver com detalhe por que alguns casos não rodaram.

No entanto, vendo que os seus três nós estão dando erro, vale a pena você verificar se a função mapas está funcionando para o primeiro elemento da `lista_sp`.